# Is there a name/term for the number range represented by sine and cosine

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Is there a name/term for the number range represented by sine and cosine?

I'm not sure how to ask this so I'll ask it as the following word question

- -180 to +180 is to degrees as
- -π to +π is to radians as
- -1 to +1 is to _______?

Is there a word that fits in _______ above?

Comment: The interval [-1,+1] is the *image* (or range) of the function sin(x) and of the function cos(x), whereas [-180,180] and [-$\pi$,$\pi$] are domains.

Comment: Its name is $[-1,1]$.